# Calculate total number of if-else clauses(including nested)

Tags: java, parsing, if-statement, javaparser

Need to calculate the number of if-else clauses. I'm using java parser to do it.

What I've done till now:
I've obtained the count of all if and else-if clauses by using the function

```
node.getChildNodesByType(IfStmt.class))
```

**Problem:**
How do I count the else clauses? 
This function ignores the "else" clause.

**Example:**

```
if(condition)
{ 
     if(condition 2)
       //
     else
 }

 else if(condition 3)
{
     if (condition 4) 
      // 
     else
}
 else
{
   if(condition 5) 
      // 
}
```

In this case, I'd want the answer to be 8 but the size of the call will return 5 because it encounters only 5 "if's" and ignores the else clauses. Is there any function that can directly help me count the else clauses?

**My code:**

```
  public void visit(IfStmt n, Void arg) 
            {
            System.out.println("Found an if statement @ " + n.getBegin());
            }

            void process(Node node)
            {
                count=0;
                for (Node child : node.getChildNodesByType(IfStmt.class))
                {
                    count++;
                   visit((IfStmt)child,null);   
                }
            }
```

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552443/google-javaparser-ifstmt-not-counting-consequent-else-if

Comment: @Berger I did go through that. The problem arising is that it does not account for nested if-else.
OP's example in that question is different from mine and that answer does not work with this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been **solved** on the following github [thread](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/946). 
The in-built methods of the java parser are more than sufficient to help out.

**Answer:**

```
 static int process(Node node) {
    int complexity = 0;
    for (IfStmt ifStmt : node.getChildNodesByType(IfStmt.class)) {
        // We found an "if" - cool, add one.
        complexity++;
        printLine(ifStmt);
        if (ifStmt.getElseStmt().isPresent()) {
            // This "if" has an "else"
            Statement elseStmt = ifStmt.getElseStmt().get();
            if (elseStmt instanceof IfStmt) {
                // it's an "else-if". We already count that by counting the "if" above.
            } else {
                // it's an "else-something". Add it.
                complexity++;
                printLine(elseStmt);
            }
        }
    }
    return complexity;
}
```